# "Invalid call" when trying to dynamically import local SVG in React Native

Tags: react-native, svg, import

I'm trying to dynamically import local SVG files with Suspense and lazy in React Native (v0.72.3). But I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR  [Error: TransformError Utils/DynamicSvg.tsx: Utils/DynamicSvg.tsx:Invalid call at line 13: import(url)]
Error: Utils/DynamicSvg.tsx:Invalid call at line 13: import(url)
    at transformJS (/Users/me/projects/myproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:225:15)
    at transformJSWithBabel (/Users/me/projects/myproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:343:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.transform (/Users/me/projects/myproj/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js:461:12)
```

Here is my code:

```
import { Suspense, lazy } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

export const DynamicSvg = ({name}: any) => {
  
  console.log("name: " + name);
  const LazySvg = lazy(() => {
    const url = `./../assets/people/${name}`;
    
    return import(url);
  });

  return (
    <Suspense>
      <LazySvg />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix it?

Comment: Dynamic imports with react lazy are not supported in react native(React Native does not use webpack for bundling - which is required for dynamic imports using import() ). Use the require syntax for dynamic imports in React Native.

Answer (score 0):

The React Native doesn't support `SVG` syntax or file directly. So to fix this you must follow the installation guide:

1. Install [`react-native-svg`](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-svg)
2. Install [`react-native-svg-transformer`](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer).

Then inside your project components, you can write like the following:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import YourSvgFile from './assets/svg/yourSvgFile.svg';

const TheComponent = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <YourSvgFile />
    </View>
  );
};
```

It does work, if you need to make a dynamic one, you should pre-import them and write like the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import HomeIcon from '../icons/home.svg';
import ShopIcon from '../icons/shop.svg';
import SearchIcon from '../icons/search.svg';

const IconMap = {
  home: HomeIcon,
  shop: ShopIcon,
  search: SearchIcon,
} as const;

type IconMapNamesType = keyof typeof IconMap;

interface DynamicSvgProps {
  name: IconMapNamesType;
}

const DynamicSvg: React.FC<DynamicSvgProps> = ({ name }) => {
  const Icon = IconMap[name];

  if(!Icon) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Icon />
    </View>
  );
};
```